# Bisection Method and midpoint

Tags: numerical-methods

If $f(a) < 0$ and $f(b) > 0$, then prove that the point $c$ computed in the bisection
method is the point where the line through $(a, \operatorname{sign}(f(a)))$ and $(b, \operatorname{sign(f(b))})$
intersects the $x$-axis.

Can anyone give me hints on this homework question of mine?

Comment: Sketch it. ${}{} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a, sign(f(a)) = (a, -1)$, $(b, sign(f(b)) = (b, +1)$. This is because $f(a) < 0$, hence $sign(f(a)) = -1$ and vice versa for $sign(f(b))$.

Now, the straight line between $(a, -1)$ and $(b, +1)$ has slope

$$
m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} = \frac{+1 - -1}{b - a} = \frac{2}{b - a}
$$

Hence, the general equation of the line is
$$
y  - y_1 = m(x - x_1) \\
y - 1 = \frac{2}{b - a}(x - b)
$$

The $x$ intercept is found where $y = 0$.

Plugging that into the equation yields

$$
0 - 1 = \frac{2}{b - a}(x - b) \\
-1 (b - a) = 2(x - b) \\
a - b = 2x - 2b \\
2x = a + b \\
x = \frac{a + b}{2}
$$

Which is the exact point that the bisection method yields (the point with $x= \frac{a + b}{2}$)